# Duda sobre que hay que añadir para poder impimir por pantalla tres columnas

Tags: c++, estructuras-de-datos

Solo me falta saber como puedo seguir elaznado el bucle para así me consiga imprimir las tres columas que necesito, algo parecido a la foto

---

El txt base que uso es este, que lo he ido porbando tanto con guiones como con espacios y me gustaria saber como puedo tambien que me lo muestre por pantalla pero usnado espacios o tabulaciones

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y como se muestra en la imagen solo consigo sacar hasta el Bastidor y Modelo
y deberia ir saliendo varias filas del estilo "Bastidor: %s Modelo: %s Color: %s

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias por la ayuda

---

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

typedef struct{
    char *Bastidor;
    char Modelo;
    char Color;
}vehiculos;

vehiculos *coches;
void vaciar(char temp[]);
void copiar (char temp[],int i);

int main()
{
    int i,j,x;
    char aux;
    char temp [301];
    int cont = 0;

    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("Bastidores_modelos_colores_coches.txt","r");
    if (f== NULL){
        printf("No se ha podido abrir el fichero.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    while(!feof(f)){
        fgets(temp,301,f);
        cont++;
    }

    rewind(f);

    coches = (vehiculos*)malloc(cont*sizeof(vehiculos));
    if (coches == NULL){
        printf("No se ha podido reservar la memoria.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    for(i= 0; !feof(f); i++){
        vaciar(temp);
        aux = '0';
        for(j=0; aux !='-';j++){
            aux = fgetc(f);
            if(aux != '-'){
                temp[j] = aux;
            }
        }
        copiar(temp,i);

        fgets(temp,301,f);


        printf("Bastidor: %s Modelo: %s Color: %s.\n",coches[i].Bastidor,coches[i].Modelo,coches[i].Color);
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void vaciar(char temp[]){
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i< 301; i++){
        temp[i] ='\0';
    }
}

void copiar(char temp[], int i){
    int N = strlen(temp)+1;
    coches[i].Bastidor =(char*)malloc(N*sizeof(char));
    if (coches[i].Bastidor == NULL){
        printf("No se ha podido reservar memoria.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    strcpy(coches[i].Bastidor,temp);
}
```

---

Comment: Si la pregunta es de C++... ¿Cómo es que no usas nada propio de C++ como `std::string`, `std::ifstream`, `std::cout`, ...? Esto parece un programa de C en el que se te ha colado una línea propia de C++ (`using namespace std;`), la cual te podrías haber ahorrado porque aquí no sirve absolutamente para nada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El código que publicas tiene varios defectos:

- No es C++, es C
- Los nombres de variables están muy mal escogidos: `cont` (¿continuación? ¿contenedor? ¿contador? ¿contagios?), `aux` (???), `temp` (???), `f` (???). Use nombres comprensibles por todo el mundo, sobre todo si pretende pedir y recibir ayuda.
- Use `#define` para valores fijos, sobre todo si se usan más de una vez.
- Reinventa la rueda para funcionalidades definidas en los estándares más básicos (por ejemplo, tokenizar un string según ocurrencia de uno o más caracteres con `strtok_r`, y copiarlos a un string con `strcpy` o semejantes).
- Si, a pesar de ello, prefiere trabajar sobre caracteres en vez de strings:

  - La función `vaciar` no debería existir: usted debería añadir un `0` una vez haya concluido de generar el string.
  - No debería inventarse un valor aleatorio para conseguir que la condición del bucle se cumpla en su primera vuelta.
  - No le recomiendo leer ficheros carácter por carácter: lea líneas completas y trabaje con arrays usando las herramientas básicas de C (por ejemplo: `linea[i]`).
- No rellena los valores de `vehiculos.Modelo` ni `vehiculos.Color`, que deberían ser `char[]` o `char*` para albergar un string o un apuntador a un string, respectivamente (con `char` solo puede albergar un carácter).
- No libera la memoria reservada ni cierra el fichero abierto.
- Leer el fichero por completa para contar las líneas y reservar memoria y luego leerlo para analizarlo es mala idea. Le recomiendo que use `realloc` para ir ampliando la memoria reservada a medida que va avanzando ene la lectura del fichero, o use listas de apuntadores (con `p->next`, por ejemplo).
- En la medida de lo posible, evite usar variables globales. Si aún cree que necesta la función `copiar` (lo pongo en duda), pásele un apuntador al objeto en vez del índice al array declarado global.

Nos quedaría algo así:

```c
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_LEN 301
#define NOMBRE_FICHERO "Bastidores_modelos_colores_coches.txt"

typedef struct{
    char *Bastidor;
    char *Modelo;
    char *Color;
}Vehiculos;

int cuenta_lineas(FILE*file);
char* copia(char**destino, char*origen);

enum {BASTIDOR = 0, MODELO, COLOR};

int main(void)
{
    Vehiculos *coches;
    FILE*file;
    int n_coches, i;
    char linea[MAX_LEN];

    file = fopen(NOMBRE_FICHERO, "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("No se ha podido abrir el fichero.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    n_coches = cuenta_lineas(file);
    coches = (Vehiculos*) malloc(n_coches * sizeof(Vehiculos));

    if (coches == NULL) {
        printf("No se ha podido reservar la memoria.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    for (i = 0; fgets(linea, MAX_LEN, file) != NULL; i++) {
        char *str, *token, *saveptr;
        int j;
        for (j = 0, str = linea; ; str = NULL, j++) {
            token = strtok_r(str, "-\r\n", &saveptr);

            if (token == NULL) {
                break;
            }

            switch(j) {
                case BASTIDOR:
                    copia(&(coches[i].Bastidor), token);
                    break;
                case MODELO:
                    copia(&(coches[i].Modelo), token);
                    break;
                case COLOR:
                    copia(&(coches[i].Color), token);
                    break;
                default:
                    printf("Número de campo desconocido en línea %d: %d\n", i, j);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n_coches; i++) {
        printf("Coche %d:\n", i);
        printf(" - Bastidor: %s\n", coches[i].Bastidor);
        printf(" - Modelo: %s\n", coches[i].Modelo);
        printf(" - Color: %s\n", coches[i].Color);

        free(coches[i].Bastidor);
        free(coches[i].Modelo);
        free(coches[i].Color);
    }

    free(coches);
    fclose(file);
}

int cuenta_lineas(FILE*file)
{
    int n_lineas = 0;
    char linea[MAX_LEN];
    while (fgets(linea, MAX_LEN, file) != NULL) {
        n_lineas++;
    }

    rewind(file);

    return n_lineas;
}

char* copia(
    char**destino,
    char*origen)
{
    *destino = (char*) malloc( (strlen(origen) + 1) * sizeof(char) );
    if (*destino == NULL) {
        printf("No se ha podido reservar la memoria.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    return strcpy(*destino, origen);
}
```